# XML to array skips attribute values

Tags: php, xml

I am converting XML into array using PHP as

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);
$content= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
$data = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($content,null,null,"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/")), TRUE);
```

**It gives array but skip attribute values**

```
<xml>
  <add:location xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <add:addresses>
      <add:houseNumber xml:lang="ENG" type="house">value</add:houseNumber>
      <add:city type="metro">value</add:city>
    </add:addresses>
  </add:location>
</xml>
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [location] => Array
        (
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                    [houseNumber] => value
                    [city] => value
                )

        )
)
```

I want values of attributes also in array so I can get values of type,lang against respective nodes

Comment: Why do you `json_encode` and `json_decode` as array? That operation is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa this is some kind of hack to encode object to json and then get array without iterating and all this stuff over `XMLElement`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something of this sort

```
$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);
$content= simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);
foreach($content->location->addresses->houseNumber->attributes() as $a => $b) {
 echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

Fundamentally, you need to address the attributes using `whatever->attributes()`

Since you want everything in array notation, you can iterate through these and push them into an array or apply `json_encode` `json_decode` as you've already figured out in your example.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I posted sample XML. original XML it too large to go like this. Also run time how I can map type house to housenumber and type metro to city

Comment: In that  case, you may use foreach to iterate over all objects, and recursively keep building the array.